# dynamically create html img element with preloaded image synchronously

Tags: jquery, html, image, synchronous

**assume the following:**

a) I have an image object created like so:

```
var myImage = new Image()
myImage.src = filepath
```

b) myImage has 100% loaded, filepath is valid, and is a totally appropriate image object

c) I dynamically create an image element via JQuery

```
var bitmap = $('<img />')
```

---

**What I want to do**

So far, the bitmap element is synchronously created.  How can I get the already loaded *myImage*, to display inside my *bitmap* element synchronously?

Comment: use myImage's class or id & assign its src to your bitmap's src.

Comment: `var bitmap = $('<img />', {src: image.src})`, as a sidenote I think your conceptions of synchronous images are wrong.

Comment: Or, you could just do... `var bitmap = $(myImage);`

Answer (score 0):

Add following code

```
var bitmap = $('<img>').attr('src', filepath);
```

because following code already loaded the image and this image get cached by browser

```
var myImage = new Image()
myImage.src = filepath
```

Therefore "bitmap" wont download image again rather it will used cached image.

Comment: for reference visit this link [tutorial](http://zainultutorials.blogspot.in/2013/11/preload-images-using-javascript.html)